# Installing 8' HORIZONTAL fence (4' high) on existing posts with an 8' span?

Tags: fence

I have an existing 4 ft high vertical wood fence that is old and falling apart (about 200 ft total). The existing posts however are sturdy, solid and in good shape - the posts are about 7.5' apart (around 88"). I want to replace the vertical fence with a horizontal design and use the existing 8' span posts, with about a 1" gap between the boards (would be about 7 boards high for a 4' fence). I understand (after some research) that there is the possibility of sagging with an 8' span between horizontal boards.

Is there a creative solution or fix to avoid the possible sagging without the expense of adding another cemented post in between the existing 8' posts? Like perhaps a middle vertical support/stiffener between the 8' posts, or maybe using thicker boards than traditional, or even an 8" wide board instead of 6" wide? How about a crossbeam (like an X) between each 8' span? There are 24 good posts and I'd really like to find a way to avoid the cost and time of replacing perfectly solid posts!

I'm open to imaginative structural ideas to keep the horizontal design with 8' span from sagging. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  I wasn't describing a 3-rail fence.  I added more detail to clarify my situation.  This fence just surrounds a regular grass front yard , no farm animals to contain.

Comment: An 8' span with a board vertically oriented along its thick dimension supporting nothing but its own weight shouldn't sag much at all. Before going down the redesign route, just test it - get one of the boards you plan to use, support it both ends, and see how much sag there actually is.

Comment: I like that idea to test the span! But I do wonder, if there's gonna be sag on an 8' cedar board, will it take a few years? Google doesn't seem to know...

Comment: Yes, most wood will sag somewhat over time. A live test doesn't tell you much other than by guessing based on bounce.

Comment: I'm not sure how a 3-rail fence and a 7-rail fence are different, structurally. Each rail has to support itself. As Ecnerwal says, it's entirely a matter of rail dimensions. 1x6 board are traditionally used with success.

Comment: Right, I already have a 1x6 horizontal fence that hasn't sagged after 5 years.

Comment: Not quite sure the purpose of the fence here, but if the aesthetics aren't a problem, could you add a diagonal member from the bottom of each post to the top horizontal member?  Like you see on gates all the time, except on a stationary panel.

Comment: TL;DR: any of your suggested methods should work just fine. They all have a different aesthetic and it's up to you to choose the one you like best.

Answer (score 1):

Should just be a matter of sufficiently thick/wide planks for whatever purpose the fence serves. Keeping your bulls or pigs contained is a bit different than delineating the line between your daisy field and the formal lawn.

Way down on the cheap, easy, and low-maintenance end is polytape, which I call "fake board electric fencing" (which you don't have to energize if your use does not need it) which is just a wide white tape (typically plastic and stainless steel construction) that looks somewhat like a board fence from a distance.